# use of string when passing function as argument

Tags: javascript, string, function, arguments

The following script (courtesy of [Adam Khoury](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_6CqjQ-L8Q)) creates a timer which gives a message upon completion. The functionality makes sense to me, but I am struggling to understand the use of strings here. Particularly:

1) Why must `'countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")'` be passed as a string?  In other examples I have seen, setTimeout can accept a function (without 'quotes').

2) Likewise, in that same line, why must `elem` be passed as a string (using "quotes")? It seems that the `elem` variable already holds a string value, the name of the id (`"status"`)

If you have any light to shed on this, or misconceptions to correct, I'll be grateful!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countDown(secs,elem) {
var element = document.getElementById(elem);
element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
if(secs < 1) {
clearTimeout(timer);
element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';

}
secs--;
var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">countDown(10,"status");</script>
```

Comment: it is passed as a string because `setTimeout` supports evaluation of script passed as string. you can pass in a function, or a string with code in it.

Comment: He's doing it wrong... that's considered bad practice. You can pass an anonymous function `setTimeout(function(){ countDown(secs, elem) })`

Comment: @akonsu - do other js methods support that? (Which, how do I know when that can be done...?)

Comment: @GregoryTippett I do not remember what other methods support that. `setInterval` for sure. Whenever you use a method you can look it up and see if it supports that.

Comment: @akonsu thanks, can you recommend a location or two to look it up? I have not found a js equivalent to the php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Comment: the MDN is useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why must `'countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")'` be passed as a string?

It doesn't have to be passed like that. Although `setTimeout` accepts a string, you should **avoid** passing a string. You will see its limitations quickly when you somehow try to call the callback function with an object. Passing a function is a much better approach.

> Likewise, in that same line, why must elem be passed as a string (using "quotes")? It seems that the elem variable already holds a string value, the name of the id ("status")

That's right, `elem` is already a string, but if you omit the quotes, you will create a string such as

```
'countDown(10, status)'
```

If `setTimeout` is evaluating the string later on, it will try to access for a variable `status`, which does not exist. That's why you want to the final string to look like

```
'countDown(10, "status")'
```

and for that you have to add the quotation marks.

---

So, a cleaner implementation would be

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    countDown(secs, elem);
}, 1000);
```

Note that the code is actually not working correctly. The `timer` variable is wrongly scoped, doesn't have any effect and `setTimeout` will still be called even if `secs < 1`.

It should probably be like this:

```
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    if(secs < 1) {
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
        return;
    }
    else {
         element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        countDown(secs - 1, elem);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: ok, I'm getting the picture. Thanks for your thorough response! I'm still not clear though - in your implementation, `elem` is passed without quotes. But since concatenation is used in his example, why was the `""` necessary, since `elem` was already stored as the string `"status"`?

Comment: this I will have to think more on, and experiment with writing the string value in various ways. it seems to me that the quoteless `elem` should be interpreted as a variable when the string specifying the `countDown` function is passed. BUT clearly I'm wrong about that! :)  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Gregory: The value of `elem` is `"status"`. Without the quotes, the function call will look like `countDown(status)`. I.e. the *variable* `status` is passed to the function. With quotes, the *string* `"status"` is passed: `countDown("status")` (and that's what we want). In my implementation I don't need quotes because I'm passing the variable directly to the function, not the value itself (that's a consequence of passing a function to `setTimeout` instead of a string).

Comment: I think I see... since it is in the context of a string, it sort of 'absorbs' the value of `elem` as "more string". Not to drag this on, but can you explain more about why `timer` is wrongly scoped, and how it it could be rightly scoped if one wanted to go that route? From a newbie perspective, the script does do what he says it will do.

Comment: @Gregory: `timer` is not persistent between function calls. At the line `clearTimeout(timer);`, `timer` has no value yet because `var timer = ...` is the last line of the function. Besides, you only have to call `clearTimeout` when you want to prevent the execution of a currently scheduled timeout. But when `countDown` runs, there is no other timeout scheduled. While the code seems like it does what it says, it keeps calling `countDown`, even after `sec < 1`. The text of the element is just changed so quickly that it seems that the function is not running anymore.

Comment: @Gregory: If you wanted to scope `timer` properly, you'd have to define it in global scope and use `timer = ...` instead of `var timer = ....`. But as I said, clearing the timeout is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

best practice

```
setTimeout(function(){

countDown(secs,elem);

},3000)
```

Comment: why is this best practice? :)

Comment: Because you dont need to build string and send parameters like that, its easy to send parameters, easy to understand,and you can use multiple statements too

Comment: Mainly because passing a string triggers `eval`, you don't want that. A user can pass potentially dangerous code in there, `secs = ');while(true){};'` will probably freeze the browser.